# SignalR отправить клиенту PartialView

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

Через функцию "addNewOrder" клиент получает модель для вставки, а что бы ее вставить в страницу использует ajax что бы получить PartialView в виде html.

Но зачем создавать еще один запрос если я могу через SignalR вернуть PartialView(вместо модели) через функцию "addNewOrder".

Но в клиенте в таком случае я получаю объект(ActionResult), а не html.

Как это сделать?

контроллер:

```
ActionResult view =
     PartialView("~/Views/Orders/OrderPartial.cshtml", order);
view.ExecuteResult(this.ControllerContext);
WorkspaceHub.AddNewOrder(UserName, view);
```

Хаб:

```
 public static void AddNewOrder(String  userName, ActionResult order)
 {
    hubContext.Clients.User(userName).addNewOrder(order);
 }
```

Клиент:

```
 workspace.client.addNewOrder = function (order) {     
        $('#Orders').append(order);
        console.log(order);
  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2759898/1216425 вот так не хотите случаем рендерить вью в строку?

Comment: @teran, видел. Как то хардкорно, нужно разобраться почему в одном случае приходит html, а в другом объект.

Comment: а с чего в вашем случае должна получиться строка?

Comment: а с чего она получается в обычном случае?